# SQL WHERE LIKE syntax doesn't work in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I've a table in MySQL named as **Customer**. This is the table:

```
 -------------------------------------------------
| ID |      COMPANY_NAME        |      STATUS     |
 -------------------------------------------------
|  1 |  HUMBAHAS MAN            |      ACTIVE     |
|  2 |  HUMBAHAS MAN, CO        |    NOT-ACTIVE   |
```

I'm trying to get data of **status column** based on the **company_name** as condition.

But I need the company_name not in sensitive case, so I get data use `HUMBAHAS`, or `HUMBAHAS MAN, CO`

I've successfully get the data using this

Example:

> SELECT `status` FROM `customer` WHERE `company_name` LIKE '%HUMBAHAS% LIMIT 1'

I'll get result like this in MySQL:

```
 ----------------
|     STATUS     |
 ----------------
|     ACTIVE     |
```

But I got an **empty array** in PHP. This is the code I've used in my PHP script

```
 $connection = \Yii::$app->db;
 $sql = $connection->createCommand("SELECT status from customer WHERE company_name = '%$nama%' LIMIT 1");
 $exec = $sql->queryColumn();
 print_r($exec);

 //result
 Array
 (
 )
```

How do I can make that syntax work well in my PHP script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP sql query syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987125/php-sql-query-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using  **"="** instead of **LIKE** for string match in your query.
Just replace

```
$sql = $connection->createCommand("SELECT status from customer WHERE company_name = '%$nama%' 
LIMIT 1");
```

with

```
$sql = $connection->createCommand("SELECT status from customer WHERE company_name like '%$nama%'
LIMIT 1");
```

It will work for you.

Comment: yeah you're. I forgot that one :D Thankyou

Comment: This query is vulnerable to **SQL Injection**.

Answer (score 0):

You should to type like this :

> ```
> $sql="SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `title` LIKE '?'";
> $result= $conn->prepare($sql);
> $result->bindValue(1,''%text%'');
> $result->execute();
> ```
>
> it`s will work .
>
> ```
> %text%
> ```

END